# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined spring+thymeleaf+datatables

Tags: spring-mvc, datatables, thymeleaf

Im using an AJAX request to get the results from the controller to populate them in the datatable. The results are returned from the controller in JSON format but I keep getting the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` error.

Are there anymore datatable parameters I should set in the controller?

The controller class:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/list", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<User> listOfUsers() {
    List<User> usersList;
    usersList = userService.getAllUsers();
    return usersList;
}
```

Datatable UI in thymeleaf :

```
           <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="usersTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover dataTable">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th th:text="#{user.table.heading.username}">User Name</th>
                            <th th:text="#{systemUser.table.heading.firstname}">First Name</th>
                            <th th:text="#{systemUser.table.heading.lastname}">Last Name</th>
                            <th th:text="#{systemUser.table.heading.status}">Status</th>
                            <th th:text="#{systemUser.table.heading.role}">Role</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

AJAX request :

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#usersTable').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        dataType: 'json',
        "ajax": {
            "url": "http://localhost:8080/sample/users/list",
            "type": "GET"
        },
        "columns": [
            {"data": "username"},
            {"data": "firstName"},
            {"data": "lastName"},
            {"data": "status"},
            {"data": "roleName"}
        ]
    })
});
</script>
```

The JSON response :

```
[  
 {  
  "id":1,
  "username":"dinesh@example.com",
  "firstName":dinesh,
  "lastName":damian,
  "password":"$2a$10dfgfdgfdgd6O.iO6XB5xcyEZuppAHWOZGwX8m8xCLqS",
  "status":"ACTIVE",
  "role":{  
     "id":1,
     "roleName":"ADMIN",
     "status":"ACTIVE",
     "permissionList":[  
        {  
           "id":1,
           "name":"ROLE_LOGIN",
           "description":"User login permission",
           "checked":false
        }
     ],
     "checkedPermissions":[  

     ]
  }
```

}
]

Comment: In your json response, your userlist must be in `'data'` element. Like `'data' = usersList`

Comment: so how can i manipulate the JSON into that format?

Comment: I don't know how to do it in spring mvc sorry.

Comment: 1. Your table has 5 rows, while JSON response gives 7 -- 'id' and 'password' are missing. You should add {"data": "id", bVisible: false} and the other one, too.
2. There's no 'roleName' on the JSON 1st level, there's 'role'

Answer (score 0):

Usually [Cannot read property ‘length’ of undefined](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-common-javascript-console-errors/#typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined) means that DataTables cannot find the data in the response.

Use the following initialization options to match your response structure.

```
$('#usersTable').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    dataType: 'json',
    "ajax": {
        "url": "http://localhost:8080/sample/users/list",
        "type": "GET",
        "dataSrc": ""
    },
    "columns": [
        {"data": "username"},
        {"data": "firstName"},
        {"data": "lastName"},
        {"data": "status"},
        {"data": "role.roleName"}
    ]
});
```

See [`ajax.dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It was successfully rendered after changing the AJAX request into this.

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#usersTable').DataTable({
        "sAjaxSource": "http://localhost:8080/sample/users/list",
        "sAjaxDataProp": "",
        "aoColumns": [
            {"mData": "username"},
            {"mData": "firstName"},
            {"mData": "lastName"},
            {"mData": "status"},
            {"mData": "role.roleName"}

        ]
    })
});
<script th:inline="javascript">
```